# Do XOR follow any pattern for the sequence, n⊕(n+1)⊕(n+2)⊕(n+3) , when n is odd?

Tags: math, xor

[XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) -> ⊕

XOR of 4 consecutive integers
n⊕(n+1)⊕(n+2)⊕(n+3)  -- **Equation 1**

We know by property of XOR that, Equation 1 = 0 ,    for n=eve

I am struggling to find any property/sequence when n is odd.

Does XOR of 4 consecutive positive integer follow any property when starting element of sequence is odd?

I was able to proof the sequence for n=eve(when starting element of sequence is eve).
I tried brute forcing the equation, using a program but was unable to gain any significant output.

Output for brute forcing n=65 to 103;

```
Starting element      Result
65                     4
67                     4
69                     12
71                     12
73                     4
75                     4
77                     28
79                     28
81                     4
83                     4
85                     12
87                     12
89                     4
91                     4
93                     60
95                     60
97                     4
99                     4
101                     12
103                     12
```

Comment: Since you're looking at n,n+1,n+2,n+3, it makes sense to consider the value of n not just modulo 2 (even or odd) but modulo 4. There are two possibilities modulo 4 if you know that n is odd: n ≡ 1 (mod 4) and n ≡ 3 (mod 4). In binary, this corresponds to n ending in 01 or ending in 11. If n ≡ 1 (mod 4), then n,n+1,n+2,n+3 are going to end in 01, 10, 11, 00, respectively, and n+3 is going to get a carry. If n ≡ 3 (mod 4), then n,n+1,n+2,n+3 are going to end in 11,00,01,10, respectively, and n+1,n+2,n+3 are all going to get a carry.

Comment: There clearly is a pattern. The entries that are not 1*4 take the values 3*4, 7*4, 15*4, 31*4, 63*4, 2**n-1 and each of those occur are regular intervals. FWIW, I don't think this question is a programming question in its present form, which makes it off-topic.

Comment: @Stef we can know the last 2 digits of the output, but is there any way to know the output without actually calculating it.  Like this can be a subproblem in a XOR query range problem, if we calculate XOR like naive approach the complexity will be big. So is there any way to predict the answer without actually calculating it?

Comment: @njuffa well this can be made into a programming easily, example :                                                    
 Given a range [L,R] and a number k, find the number of 4 consecutive numbers that produce output as k.

Comment: @shivam01-0 Yes. Of course we can. Try on a few examples and see what happens. And by "try" I mean do it by hand, looking at the bits. Don't just have a program that tells you 85->12 without showing you what happened to the bits and why it happened.

Comment: @shivam01-0 The result can be computed differently, but whether that helps or not in practical terms is unclear since the question is posed as a mathematical one rather than in context of a particular programming task. For example, for odd `a`, we have: `uint32_t extract_lowest_block_of_ones (uint32_t a) { return ((a + 1) & ~a) - 1; } uint32_t func (uint32_t a) { return (extract_lowest_block_of_ones (a / 4) * 2 + 1) * 4; }`